# twig array by order in controller

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have a array in my controller: arr = 94, 75, 97, 26 
When I  get my array with a for loop it shows: 26, 75, 94, 97
How can I get my array without changing the order?

```
{% for number in numbers %}

    {% set number = numberViewModel.number.id %}

    {{ number }}

{% endfor %}
```

I want 94, 75, 97, 26
NOT
26, 75, 94, 97

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop like this:

```
{% for i in 1..3 %}
    {{ numbers[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This presumes numbers is an array passed in.

I created a TwigFiddle for you:
https://twigfiddle.com/yqld3j